# Open form module from popup

Tags: 7, forms, javascript

I have a basic module that I made for a survey/email collection form for a site I'm building. I'm very new to drupal and drupal development and I'm trying to figure out how to open this module on the front page after a click on a button inside of a popup of some sort, I was thinking jquery modal or something of the sort. I can't figure out heads or tails from it and don't even know where to put anything. So far I just have the module files survey.info and survey.module. Do I have to modify theme files or what? Sorry for being so green but the development files online aren't very cut and dry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Drupal!

Take a look at https://drupal.org/project/modal_forms - this performs the functionality that you've described and works with https://drupal.org/project/webform which you can use to build the survey.

I also recommend taking a look at https://drupal.org/project/examples to learn more about module building in general; it includes many practical examples.

If you want to use an existing form, check out the tutorial at http://deeson-online.co.uk/labs/insert-form-pop-modal-ctools-and-drupal-7 that describes how to use CTools Modal with existing forms.

Comment: Thanks! What if I already have all of the survey built? It's all in a module and I need that module to display? Will this still work? I'll poke around with it until I get your response!

Comment: I've added a link to a tutorial that describes how to use CTools Modal with existing forms, does that help?